# Amazon service equivalent to Rackspace's cloud sites?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rackspace-cloud

I was wondering if any of you know an Amazon equivalent version of cloud sites from rackspace. I know they have services similar to cloud servers and files but not this?

Basically, I'm looking for a scalable web server managed by them, *** but (this is what cloud sites can't do) I want to still be able to do things in the backend and install other apps etc.. (like my own server)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having experience with both Rackspace and Amazon, I can tell you that the two traits you are looking for are somewhat mutually exclusive, as scalability like that requires a certain level of control by the provider.

The best solution would be to use something like Rackspace Cloud Servers, and then scale via the API when required.